# sending emails from django

Tags: django

I have a database containing subscribers and data on them I also have an restful api setup to receive and send data from/to the database.

I want to make a front end in Django to send and create the emails using django templates to customize the emails I send.

So I want to provide a query to django, which sends that to the db API returning a list of emails and necessary info.  Django will then construct personalized emails using JSON data that the database returned as context for the templates and then passes the email and email address to a function that uses Sendgrid's API to send the email to my subscriber.

Does this sound like a good way of doing this?  Also could anyone give me any tips or pointers on how to best making such a thing?

Answer (score 2):

SendGrid's API can do replacement values from associative arrays that you provide via the Python API from Django.

Instead of sending n * individual-emails, you can group the recipients into BCC's and send 1 email, which SendGrid's API will then take replace the specified pieces of text with the replacement values. It's pretty simple to do. Also check out https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python to make your life a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this sort of thing in the past with custom management commands. It's essentially a Python script that easily accesses your Django data, and lets you do essentially anything Python is capable of. You can then easily schedule the job with cron, ball up data as JSON and pass it around, or whatever else you desire with it as a stand-alone script.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-management-commands/

Django has a built-in email system that works pretty well too, but it sounds like you already are set up for SMTP or whatever with SendGrid.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/email/